# How to create this icon with text inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have already created burst put facing problem with putting number inside burst.So i need help for fix it 
Need to look like Image burst.

[image]

```css
#burst-8 {
  background: #00aaad;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#burst-8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 15px;
  background: #00aaad;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `content` property

```css
#burst-8 {
  background: #00aaad;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#burst-8:after {
  content: "99";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #00aaad;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8"></div>
```

Using [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr)

```css
#burst-8 {
  background: #00aaad;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#burst-8:after {
  content: attr(data-burst);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 15px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #00aaad;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8" data-burst="99"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what you want, see if the following answer helps.

```css
#burst-8 {
  background: #00aaad;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#burst-8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 15px;
  background: #00aaad;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8">99</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you don't need to rotate the div element rotate only pseudo element and 
 then setting pseudo element to the lower level than div element with `z-index` can fix it.

Positions work as layering of elements and [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) handles layer order.

```css
#burst-8 {
  background: #00aaad;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 4px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height:25px;
}

#burst-8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #00aaad;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8">99</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#burst-8 {
  background: #00aaad;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#burst-8:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: 15px;
  background: #00aaad;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8">99</div>
```